# Searching in phone book using IDictionary

Tags: c#, dictionary, maps

I am trying to loop through the variable what i have taken as searching parameter but if i use loop the program will print 6 times "Not Found"

If i use m=0 and increment it with 1 with every increment of foreach loop it will only loop 3 times i.e., till the number of times "foreach" loop executed.

I am searcing with name1 parameter with evl.Key of dictionary phoneBook it is printing "Not Found" for every time.

```
class Solution
{
    public static void Main()
    {

        IDictionary<string, string> phoneBook = new Dictionary<string, string>();
        String[] name = new string[3];
        String[] phoneNumber = new string[3];
        for (int j = 0; j < 3; j++)
        {
            name[j] = Console.ReadLine();
            phoneNumber[j] = Console.ReadLine();
        }
        for (int i = 0; i < 3; i++)
        {
            phoneBook.Add(name[i], phoneNumber[i]);
        }
        String[] name1 = new string[3];
        for (int l = 0; l < 3; l++)
        {
            name1[l] = Console.ReadLine();
        }
        int m = 0;
        foreach (var getData in phoneBook)
        {
            if (getData.Key == name1[m])
            {
                Console.WriteLine(getData.Key + " = " + getData.Value);
            }
            else
            {
                Console.WriteLine("Not Found");
            }
            m = m + 1;
        }
    }
}
```

====================Input=====================

```
3
sam 99912222
tom 11122222
harry 12299933
sam
edward
harry
```

=====================This is my output==================

```
Not Found
Not Found
Not Found
```

=====================This will be expected output==============

```
sam=99912222
Not found
harry=12299933
```

Comment: The inconsistent indentation makes the code **very** hard to read. Also, you don't need the `phoneNumber` and `name` arrays. Just add that data directly to the dictionary - rather than into the array and **then** into the dictionary.

Comment: Read up on `string.Split` if you want the name and phone number on the same line. Also, please explain why `3` was the first input.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There were a few problems that I corrected. See comments in the code.

```
class Solution
{
    public static void Main()
    {

        IDictionary<string, string> phoneBook = new Dictionary<string, string>();
        // First line of input contains 3 which looks like the number of entries in the phone book.
        // You have to read that number first.
        int count = System.Convert.ToInt32(Console.ReadLine());
        // Then, size the string arrays to count.
        String[] name = new string[count];
        String[] phoneNumber = new string[count];
        for (int j = 0; j < 3; j++)
        {
            // Read entire line consisting of name and phone number, and split into two strings
            // consisting of name, and phone number.
            string[] parts = Console.ReadLine().Split(' ');
            name[j] = parts[0].Trim();
            phoneNumber[j] = parts[1].Trim();
        }
        for (int i = 0; i < 3; i++)
        {
            phoneBook.Add(name[i], phoneNumber[i]);
        }
        String[] name1 = new string[3];
        for (int l = 0; l < 3; l++)
        {
            name1[l] = Console.ReadLine();
        }
        // You need to check for each name0 in name1, whether it exists in dictionary.
        foreach (var name0 in name1)
        {
            string number;
            // If name0 is in the phoneBook, number is set to its phone number.
            if (phoneBook.TryGetValue(name0, out number))
            {
                Console.WriteLine(name0 + " = " + number);
            }
            else
            {
                Console.WriteLine("Not Found");
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: sam is the key value i.e., the name mapped to phone number and the search operation will be performed on the same.

Comment: Thanks @RobertBaron, i finally found my mistakes and thanks to every one for your help and support.

Comment: @Shakti - You are welcome! Do not forget to accept the answer!

Comment: @RobertBaron Your answer is really very helpful and it is acceptable to all.

Answer (score 1):

I finally found and corrected the code. The corrected code is :

```
class Solution {
  static void Main(String[] args) {
    IDictionary<string, string> phoneBook = new Dictionary<string, string>();

        int n = System.Convert.ToInt32(Console.ReadLine());

        String[] name = new string[n];
        String[] phoneNumber = new string[n];
        for (int j = 0; j < n; j++)
        {           
            string[] parts = Console.ReadLine().Split(' ');
            name[j] = parts[0].Trim();
            phoneNumber[j] = parts[1].Trim();
        }
        for (int i = 0; i < n; i++)
        {
            phoneBook.Add(name[i], phoneNumber[i]);
        }
        String[] name1 = new string[n];
        for (int l = 0; l < n; l++)
        {
            name1[l] = Console.ReadLine();
        }

        foreach (var name0 in name1)
        {
            string number;

            if (phoneBook.TryGetValue(name0, out number))
            {
                Console.WriteLine(name0 + "=" + number);
            }
            else
            {
                Console.WriteLine("Not found");
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Thanks to all contributors

Answer (score 0):

`Console.ReadLine()`, as its name suggests, reads a whole line at a time.

In other words, `name[0] = "3";` then `phoneNumber[0] = "sam 99912222";` and so on...

You will not be able to match "sam" and "harry" in the Dictionary's keys with your current code.

Don't input "3" on the first line, since you're not actually using that in your loops (as I expect you intended), then use something like String.Split() in the following code example...

```cs
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;

namespace Searching_in_phone_book_using_IDictionary
{
    class MainClass
    {
        public static void Main()
        {
            IDictionary<string, string> phoneBook = new Dictionary<string, string>();
            String[] name = new string[3];
            String[] phoneNumber = new string[3];
            for (int j = 0; j < 3; j++)
            {
                var nameAndPhoneNumber = Console.ReadLine();
                name[j] = nameAndPhoneNumber.Split(' ')[0];
                phoneNumber[j] = nameAndPhoneNumber.Split(' ')[1];
            }
            for (int i = 0; i < 3; i++)
            {
                phoneBook.Add(name[i], phoneNumber[i]);
            }
            String[] name1 = new string[3];
            for (int l = 0; l < 3; l++)
            {
                name1[l] = Console.ReadLine();
            }
            int m = 0;
            foreach (var getData in phoneBook)
            {
                if (getData.Key == name1[m])
                {
                    Console.WriteLine(getData.Key + " = " + getData.Value);
                }
                else
                {
                    Console.WriteLine("Not Found");
                }
                m = m + 1;
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I think you have a bug in your code, it's working fine only when you put in the same order your name to search in the book:

You just only need to avoid using the `m` variable and use `name1.Contains` instead like follow:

```
    foreach (var getData in phoneBook)
    {
        if (name1.Contains(getData.Key))
        {
            Console.WriteLine(getData.Key + " = " + getData.Value);
        }
        else
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Not Found");
        }
    }
```